# Regex for replacing first 5 numbers, irrespective of anything between them?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to achieve the following match

**Input**

```
123-45-6789
123456789
1234
```

**Reg Ex(s) Tried with output:**

```
\d{5}
```

123-45-6789

**12345**6789

1234

```
\d{2,3}
```

**123**-**45**-**678**9

**123456789**

**123**4

```
\d{3}-{0,1}\d{2}
```

**123-45**-6789

**12345**6789

1234

I need to supply this regex to replace method, and I don't want the "**-**" to be replaced, it should only replace the first 5 digits without changing the format:

**Expected Output**

**123**-**45**-6789

**12345**6789

1234

**EDIT**

In the above sample outputs:

1> all are matched with global regex
2> the bolded digits are only expected to be matched

**The Purpose**

I need to mask SSN, eg: 444-55-6666 becomes ###-##-6666 and 444556666 becomes #####6666. Without hampering the format.

Comment: Your expected output is the same as input, why?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please see the output in **bold**. I want only those numbers to be matched, not "-"

Comment: your last regex seems ok, what you need here is capturing groups (round brackets): `(\d{3})-{0,1}(\d{2})`. This will allow you to replace just these specific parts from the whole match

Comment: You say *I need to supply this regex to replace method, and I don't want the "-" to be replaced*. If they are replaced, what with?

Comment: I'm confused by your wording. Have you labelled the current **matches** as "output"? The matches listed for `\d{2,3}` also aren't correct, unless you've performed a global search(?). And what do you want to replace the match **with**?

Comment: @TomLord Every regex I stated is a global match. I need to mask SSN, eg: `444-55-6666` becomes `###-##-6666` and `444556666` becomes `#####6666`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match and replace those first five digits:

```js
var str = `123-45-6789
123456789
1234
`
console.log(str.replace(/^(\D*\d\D*){5}/gm, function(match) {
    return match.replace(/\d/g, '*');
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's other ways of looking at it:

- You want to ignore all non-numeric characters, and then get the first five numbers

  ```
  input.replace(/\D/g,'').substr(0,5);
  ```
- You want to match five numeric characters, wherever they may appear in the input

  ```
  input.match(/\d/g).slice(0,5);
  ```

There is almost always more than one way to approach a problem. If you can't figure out how to do what you want, try re-wording the problem until you find something you can do.