# Mask SSN using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to mask the first 5 digits of SSN numbers. I tried this code but it is not working:

```
var r = new RegExp('?:\d{3})-(?:\d{2})-(\d{4}');    
var str = '123-12-1234';        
var result = str.replace(r,'###-##-'); 

 result = ###-##-1234
```

Do I need to change the expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for replacing first 5 numbers, irrespective of anything between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275840/regex-for-replacing-first-5-numbers-irrespective-of-anything-between-them)

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss **(** and **)**. Try to edit as below:

```
var r = new RegExp('(?:\d{3})-(?:\d{2})-(\d{4})');
```